# XML to JSON conversion: why my 1st xml tag is getting skipped?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, tags

while converting XML to JSON my 1st XML tag into JSON is getting skipped

Here is the JAVA code snippet:

```
       String data="";
       data = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/resources/student.xml"), "UTF-8");
       XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
       JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(data.getBytes());
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(newFile("src/main/resources/student.json"),jsonNode);
```

here is the input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AccumulateResponse>
  <TestCase>
    <Transactionid>str1234</Transactionid>
    <TransactionType>str1234</TransactionType>
    <Status>str1234</Status>
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase>
    <Transactionid>str5678</Transactionid>
    <TransactionType>str5678</TransactionType>
    <Status>str5678</Status>
  </TestCase>
</AccumulateResponse>
```

here is the output:

```
{
  "TestCase": [
   {
    "Transactionid": "str1234",
    "TransactionType": "str1234",
    "Status": "str1234"
   },
   {
    "Transactionid": "str5678",
    "TransactionType": "str5678",
    "Status": "str5678"
   }
  ]
}
```

here is the required Output:

```
{
"AccumulateResponse": {
  "TestCase": [
   {
    "Transactionid": "str1234",
    "TransactionType": "str1234",
    "Status": "str1234"
   },
   {
    "Transactionid": "str5678",
    "TransactionType": "str5678",
    "Status": "str5678"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

AccumulateResponse tag is getting skipped.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Serge i am using java

Comment: The JSON and XML data models don't have a one-to-one correspondence and every converter deals with the differences in its own way. If you want the output in a precise format under your own control, you're probably going to have to do it yourself (e.g. in XSLT) rather than using an off-the-shelf converter.

Comment: But the conversion should give the correct output right..@MichaelKay

Answer (score 0):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AccumulateResponse>
  <TestCase>
    <Transactionid>str1234</Transactionid>
    <TransactionType>str1234</TransactionType>
    <Status>str1234</Status>
  </TestCase>
  <TestCase>
    <Transactionid>str5678</Transactionid>
    <TransactionType>str5678</TransactionType>
    <Status>str5678</Status>
  </TestCase>
</AccumulateResponse>
```

```
{
  "AccumulateResponse": {
    "TestCase": [
      {
        "Transactionid": "str1234",
        "TransactionType": "str1234",
        "Status": "str1234"
      },
      {
        "Transactionid": "str5678",
        "TransactionType": "str5678",
        "Status": "str5678"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```